# PrestaShop Block specials displaying products that are out of stock

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

We have a sales site that we want to dont display products that are non-existent in the block of "discounted products" (in module emspecials).
As mentioned in this link [link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/292746-block-specials-displaying-products-that-are-out-of-stock/) we add `` stock.`quantity`>0 `` to sql query in module source but this does not work.

```
  $sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.`out_of_stock` out_of_stock, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`,
                    pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`,
                    p.`ean13`, p.`upc`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB("'.date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00",
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_shop` image_shop
                    ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 0).'
                WHERE stock.`quantity`>0 and p.id_product = '.(int)$id_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`,
                    pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`,
                    p.`ean13`, p.`upc`, image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB("'.date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00",
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_shop` image_shop
                    ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$context->shop->id.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` ss ON (p.id_product = ss.id_product)
                WHERE ss.`quantity`>0 
                and p.id_product = '.(int)$id_product;
```